# how to insert numbers in a list c++ style using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, c++11

i have this c++ code.

```
        int range = 0;

        cin>>range;

        int input[range] = {0};

    //      inserting in array
        for(int i=0; i<range;i++)
        {
            cin >>input[i];
        }

    //  Printing out from array
        for(int i=0; i<range;i++)
        {
            cout<<input[i];
        }
```

i am wondering how to write this piece of code in python which does the same thing. i am a beginner in python so i haven't tried much things out yet.

Comment: There are any number of questions about how to enter a list of numbers already here on Stack Overflow. What did you find when you researched? Why didn't they work for you?

Comment: This have nothing to c++, don't spam tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
count = int(input())
values = [int(input()) for _ in range(count)]
for v in values:  # alternatively, print(" ".join(str(v) for v in values))
  print(v)
```

Comment: isnt there anything much simpler for a beginner to understand
or if you could just comment your codes.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Please add more information and context. What does this code do and how does this answer the user's question? If you're going to make a code-only answer, the code needs to at least be well commented.

Comment: @AlSweigart Dude, this is an answer on a marked-as-dupe question. There are better ways for you to spend your time.